# C++ nose puede iniciar el programa '%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\AppTest\'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual, visual-studio-2008

Proyecto de C++ de WinCE5 y WinCE6 usando **Visual studio 2008**, el cual necesito hacer compilar, el codigo no es el problema, el proveedor afirmo que lo entrego compilando, al intentar hacerlo andar me encontre con este error.

**nose puede iniciar el programa
'%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\AppTest'** (a modo de ejemplo)

tengo que encontrar porque no compila, pero las unicas pistas que tengo es que al ser de c++ sea una variable de entorno,ya que **%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%** me lleva a los archivos de programa, y no tengo la carpeta \AppTest\ que pide ahi en esa direccion, de ahi a que sea otra cosa el problema no tengo idea, muchas gracias al que tenga la intencion de ayudar.

Comment: Saludos. Por lo que pones puede ser una variable de entorno, que particularmente además de faltarte, no es de las predeterminadas de windows (es decir debes crearla/establecerla); adicionalmente el nombre del **exe** deberás ubicarlo (y si lo tienes) en las subcarpetas de esa variable de entorno donde es buscada.

Comment: ¿Eso ocurre compilando o ejecutando desde Visual Studio (depurando)? Si es ejecutando, en la configuración del proyecto tienes puesto que vaya a esa ruta a buscar el exe y o no tienes la variable que define la ruta, no no está el exe en esa ruta (porque no hayas compilado, por ejemplo).

Comment: Ocurre al iniciar la depuracion de visual studio 2008 usando windows mobile 6 proffesional (SDK ARMV4I), intente crear una varibale anteriormente como indica @RobertoLeOr pero posiblmente lo hice mal, no estoy seguro de que el proyecto tenga o donde tenga un .exe

Comment: El exe lo generaria en el dispositivo virtual por lo q tengo entendido, no se que hacer con esta parte %CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\AppTest\ , con el nombre de la variable de entorno que seria lo que se colocaria realmente, la ruta de la variable utilice la del .exe, estaria mal ? , ademas el proyecto tira 2 omitidos, que debo hacer con los omitidos ? o porque seria que los omite en este caso, pareceria tambien dirigirse a una carpeta enrealidad, gracias por responder